# Prodived/Required Interface vs. Generalization in Class Diagram (UML 2.0)

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I model a Security Alarm System.

I have created a Parent Class called "Sensors" and its two Child Classes called "WindowSensor" and "DoorSensor".

In the Class Diagram, do I have to associate them with *Provided/Required Interface* **OR** with *Generalization* (Taxonomic Relationship)?

Comment: When you say "Child" what do you mean ?  WindowSensor and DoorSensor inherit from Sensor ? What programming language do you use ? Could you publish your code and/or your first schema ? Because you can do the both : create a Generalization relation and create provided interface for each classes, or just a Generalization and only the parent class has provided interfaces (this last choice is usually the good one)

Comment: Java and yes I mean inheritance relationship! (Uploading in a while by editing the question)

Answer (score 1):

So if  `WindowSensor` and `DoorSensor` extend `Sensor` the latter generalizes  `WindowSensor` and `DoorSensor`.

And depending on your needs, you can add provided/required interfaces to `Sensor`. These interfaces will be inherited by `WindowSensor` and `DoorSensor`.

You can add further provided/required interfaces to `WindowSensor` and `DoorSensor` at your wish. Notably these shall be different from those already inherited from `Sensor`.

Comment: The wording in your last sentence is a bit obscure. I think it's just superfluous to re-apply the same interface already inherited. But is it wrong too? I mean, is there a constraint that forbids this?

Comment: I am not sure to understand, childs classes provide/require the same interfaces than their parent. So to require/provide the same interfaces somtething has to change but what ?

Comment: If you don't mind I'll edit your answer and you can redo/improve it.

Comment: @Kilian in fact my answer is right with or without your improvment ... I am happy to receive improvment if this is improvment.

Comment: It's basically just a rewording ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The Provided Interface and Required Interface are **mostly** used for modeling a Component's Interfaces in UML component diagram. [see reference](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/dec04/bell/index.html)

**Class Diagram vs. Component Diagram** 
There are huge differences between Class and Component (and Class Diagram and Component Diagram). It is about **Level of Detail & Scope**, The simplest way to think of it is that one component is many classes. With components you can manage the **complexity** of a **large system**.

You have **only** 3 classes: `Sensor` Class, `DoorSensor` and `WindowSensor`. You don't need any Component Diagram and any Provided Interface or Required Interface.

The simplest solution with mentioned details is **Generalization** between classes.

Comment: Well, prov./req. interfaces can as well be applied to classes. It's equivalent to a realization of an `<<interface>>`. See also p. 171 of the specs.

Comment: Your point is not so clear because the provided and required interface are defined in section 10 about behaviored classifier and Class inherit from Behaviored classifier. See fig. 10.10

Comment: @ThomasKilian, you absolutely true, But in this case, there is no need to use them

Comment: There is not any **interface** in the question. The question has only 3 classes. And trying to model them.

Comment: @granier, please see Figure 10.11 **Alternative notation for required and provided Interface**, Provided and Required Interface is not mostly used in Class Diagram in practice.

Comment: @ Gholamali-Irani it seems more a choice from your part no ? At least modeling realized and used interfaces are often used in a class diagram. This is not so far from required/provided. And you do not say that the norm does not allow to design required/provided interfaces in a class diagram but that's not usual. That's different.

Comment: OK, maybe the question is not so clear enough. Thanks @granier and Thomas Kilian.

Comment: @granier You are both right. There's always more than one way to model a thing. Just YMMV.